# When multiple browser are open, an ajax call each an every browser?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am triggering an email at a specific time using ajax call. The triggering of the email at a specific time works fine. However, the ajax call trigger it multiple time based on the number of browsers open with the same URL. What I need is to trigger the ajax call one-time only. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('getclientlist')?>/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, value) {

            var clientudo = value.Description;
            var departudo = value.Depart;
            var emailtime = value.Email_Sent;
            var hours, mins;

            function autoudoemail() {
                console.log('trigger');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>autoudoemail",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { Client_Name: clientudo, Depart: departudo },
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
            if (emailtime) {
                var et1 = emailtime.split(':');
                hours = et1[0];
                mins = et1[1];
                //get your offset to wait value
                var timetarget = forceMidnightPageReloadGetTargetTime(hours, mins).getTime();
                var timenow = new Date().getTime();
                var offsetmilliseconds = timetarget - timenow;
                //if it isn't midnight yet, set a timeout.
                if (offsetmilliseconds >= hours++) {
                    var timer = setTimeout(function() { autoudoemail() }, offsetmilliseconds);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        swal("Oops", "We couldn't connect to the server!", "error");
    }
  });
 });
```

Please advise
Thank you

Comment: A website is processed independently in each browser you opened, you can not override that, why don't you just close the others browsers ?

Comment: Thank for your response. Multiple people are login into the system from various locations and ajax will trigger for all the browsers.

Comment: If you want to do something which will not be executed for each user, you should put this code on the server (which is common to all users) not on the client part (which is different for everyone)

Comment: This is not something you can handle on the client side alone then. You will have to store the information, that you already handled whatever needs doing (or when you did it last, if this has to be performed again after a certain amount of time) on the server, so that any “additional” AJAX requests coming in after the “first” one that already did the job, can then simply do - nothing. The alternative would be to set up a proper cron for a task like this on the server, instead of doing a “poor man’s cron” by involving the clients.

Answer (score 0):

It is the default behavior.

You can try to:

- Control the availability of the call between windows of the same browsers using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)
- Move the concern server-side and use a lock or queueing approach for your email sender.

Regards,

Comment: postMessage would only help to handle what happens in multiple tabs opened in the same browser, but as I understand the question, the AJAX requests will happen from just _any_ browser where just any arbitrary site visitor currently has the page opened.

Comment: Hi Nick, Do you have sample code or URL for me to try it out?